# Oracle SQL Statement alter index and add partition

Tags: oracle

I have an index in which I have to remove one column and reindex back for rebuild:

```
ALTER INDEX <index_name> REBUILD;
```

Is it possible to add partition when I rebuild an index.  Partition will be based on one of the column index which is a datetime field. Something like:

```
ALTER INDEX <index_name> REBUILD, PARTITION BY RANGE(COLLECTIONTIME) INTERVAL     (INTERVAL '15' MINUTE)
(PARTITION INITIAL_PARTITION VALUES LESS THAN (DATE '2014-10-10') );
```

Not sure how to write the sql statement for it. Anyone can help?

Also, if it is possible will the existing records will also be partitioned?

Answer (score 1):

No its not possible to Partition a non partitioned index using rebuild in Oracle.

For partitioning an index you will need to Drop the index and then create a partitioned index.

Hope it Helps

Vishad